# Error saving image into iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opencv

I'm know trying to get into image processing for iPhone/iPad with openCV I found some good tutorials but not a lot of info.

Well, I'm trying to save an image cropped from a ROI of a larger image, XCode and Simulator didn't report any errors but after when I try to open the image saved with Finder it reports a "Damaged file or format not recognisez" error.

That's the code for cropping and saving the image (it's inserted onto face recognition tutorial from [nashruddin.com](http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Face_Detection)

```
cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(cvrect.x * scale, cvrect.y * scale, cvrect.width * scale, cvrect.height * scale));


        /* create destination image
         Note that cvGetSize will return the width and the height of ROI */

        IplImage *img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),
                                       image->depth,
                                       image->nChannels);

        cvCopy(image, img2, NULL);

        cvResetImageROI(image);

        CvAttrList attributes;

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"prueba.jpg"];

        cvSave([path UTF8String], img2, NULL, NULL, attributes);
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided

Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [cvSaveImage](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cvsave#cvSaveImage) for that. [cvSave](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/xml/yaml_persistence.html#cvSave) saves image in XML/YAML format. Or as an option you can take raw image data and get PNG/JPEG representation using `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`/`UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` and save using `[NSData writeToFile...]`

To convert IplImage to UIImage use:

```
UIImage*  CreateUIImageFromIplImage(IplImage* ipl_image) {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes: ipl_image->imageData length: ipl_image->imageSize];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(ipl_image->width, ipl_image->height,
                                        ipl_image->depth, ipl_image->depth * ipl_image->nChannels, ipl_image->widthStep,
                                        colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                        provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    UIImage* ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the color space is different in the source and target. try using different color spaces ie RGBA,BGRA combinations.
or try cvCvtColor on your iplimage to CV_RGBA2BGRA

PS: im sorry if the above has any mistakes on the correctness of spellings of functions and constants. I dont remember them exactly

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of changing the order of colors, the red and blue channels are interchanged. The original image is in BGRA colorspace (default for OpenCV), and you are saving the image as RGB. To fix this, add

cvCvtColor(mat,mat,CV_BGR2RGBA);

before the saveImage statement.